# Delete Row From 2D Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have found the code below in stack-overflow  this code is to delete row from 2D array ,   and it's successfully working in c# ,my problem is to covert it to vb.net,when I convert it it doesn't work. any help please

```
 Public Function TrimArray(ByVal rowToRemove As Integer, ByVal originalArray As Integer(,)) As Integer(,)

 Dim result As Integer(,) = New Integer(originalArray.GetLength(0) - 2, originalArray.GetLength(1) - 1) {}

    Dim i As Integer = 0, j As Integer = 0
    While i < originalArray.GetLength(0)
        If i = rowToRemove Then
            Continue While
        End If
        Dim p As Integer = 0, m As Integer = 0
        While p < originalArray.GetLength(1)
            result(j, m) = originalArray(i, p)
            m += 1
            p += 1
        End While
        j += 1
        i += 1
    End While

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: have you tried this?
http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Show your converted code, and tell us what "doesn't work"

Comment: yes .I have tried more than converter

Comment: show us your error instead of "it doesn't work"

Comment: @Werdna I got nothing in console when I run the code  ,there is no specific  error

Comment: edit your question so it has all of your code, there must be something else where.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Public Shared Function DeleteRow(rowToRemove As Integer, Array1 As Integer(,)) As Integer(,)
    Dim Array2 As Integer(,) = New Integer(Array1.GetLength(0) - 2, Array1.GetLength(1) - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0, j As Integer = 0
    While i < Array1.GetLength(0)
        If i = rowToRemove Then
            Continue While
        End If
        Dim k As Integer = 0, m As Integer = 0
        While k < Array1.GetLength(1)
            Array2(j, m) = Array1(i, k)
            m += 1
            k += 1
        End While
        j += 1
        i += 1
    End While
    Return Array2
End Function
```

Well, I did not convert it myself. And you didn't need to as well. You could have just use a code converter:

> [Code Converter | Provided by Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: @ FARHAN  ANAM well, I tried to use code converters ,but it didn't work, and so your code above..I don't  know where's  the problem

Answer (score 0):

The code is working now,thanks for all

```
Public Function DeleteRow(ByVal rowToRemove As Integer, ByVal Array1 As Integer(,)) As Integer(,)
    Dim Array2 As Integer(,) = New Integer(Array1.GetLength(0) - 2, Array1.GetLength(1) - 1) {}
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To Array1.GetLength(0) - 1

        If i = rowToRemove Then

            Continue For

        End If

        Dim k As Integer = 0, m As Integer = 0
        While k < Array1.GetLength(1)
            Array2(j, m) = Array1(i, k)
            m += 1
            k += 1
        End While

        j += 1
    Next

    Return Array2
End Function
```